# How to return user with specific ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid based on filter query

Tags: powershell, active-directory, format, comparison, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to find a user with a specific `ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid` using the powershell ActiveDirectory cmdlet `Get-ADUser`

I've already collected a `$string`=`YvCLyl0B3E2tjT6gUbW8RA==` from Azure AD that I want to base my query upon, the string is the value of the property `ImmutableID` collected using the following Azure AD cmdlet

```
PS F:\> $test=get-msoluser -UserPrincipalName niklas.jumlin@domain.com | select-object ImmutableID
PS F:\> $test

ImmutableId
-----------
YvCLyl0B3E2tjT6gUbW8RA==
```

I can successfully convert `ImmutableID` property to the format of the `ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid` property

```
PS F:\> $string=[system.convert]::FromBase64String("YvCLyl0B3E2tjT6gUbW8RA==")
PS F:\> $string
98
240
139
202
93
1
220
77
173
141
62
160
81
181
188
68
```

I can also convert the `ImmutableID` property to the format of the `ObjectGuid` property

```
PS F:\> $bytearray=[system.convert]::frombase64string("YvCLyl0B3E2tjT6gUbW8RA==")
PS F:\> [guid]$bytearray

Guid
----
ca8bf062-015d-4ddc-ad8d-3ea051b5bc44
```

If I return the `ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid` or `ObjectGUID` property of a user I'll be getting the following:

```
PS F:\>  $user=get-aduser niklas.jumlin -Properties ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid | select-object Ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid, ObjectGuid
PS F:\>  $user

Ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid  ObjectGuid
---------------------  ----------
{98, 240, 139, 202...} ca8bf062-015d-4ddc-ad8d-3ea051b5bc44
```

When comparing the two values, they both return equal.

```
PS F:\>  if ($user.ObjectGuid -eq $user."MS-DS-ConsistencyGuid") { "ok" }
ok
```

If I compare the value of `ImmutableID` in various formats with `ObjectGUID` and `ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid` they also both return equal

```
PS F:\>  if ($bytearray.guid -eq $user.ObjectGuid) { "ok" }
ok

PS F:\>  if ($string -eq $user."ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid") { "ok" }
ok
```

But I cannot seem to use the value of ImmutableID (in any format) as my input when searching for a user using `Get-ADUser -filter "ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid -eq $string"`

A few examples I've attempted:

1

```
PS F:\>  get-aduser -filter "ms-ds-consistencyGuid -eq $([GUID]$bytearray)"
get-aduser : Error parsing query: 'ms-ds-consistencyGuid -eq ca8bf062-015d4ddc-ad8d-3ea051b5bc44' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '27'.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-aduser -filter "ms-ds-consistencyGuid -eq $([GUID]$bytearray)"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

2

```
PS F:\>  get-aduser -filter "ms-ds-ConsistencyGuid -like $([system.convert]::FromBase64String('YvCLyl0B3E2tjT6gUbW8RA==') -join ' ')"
get-aduser : Error parsing query: 'ms-ds-ConsistencyGuid -like 98 240 139 202 93 1 220 77 173 141 62 160 81 181 188 68' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '32'.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-aduser -filter "ms-ds-ConsistencyGuid -like $([system.convert]::F ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

UPDATE: The following works, but I cannot figure out how to filter for `ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid`

3

```
PS F:\>  get-aduser -filter "objectguid -eq '$([GUID]$bytearray)'"


DistinguishedName : CN=Jumlin Niklas,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : Niklas
Name              : Jumlin Niklas
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : ca8bf062-015d-4ddc-ad8d-3ea051b5bc44
SamAccountName    : niklas.jumlin
SID               : S-1-5-21-1356814742-1182796210-879972363-148862
Surname           : Jumlin
UserPrincipalName : niklas.jumlin@domain.com
```

Comment: This is indeed about Azure AD. `ImmutableID` and `ms-DS-ConsistencyGuid` are both Azure AD unique properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
$string=[system.convert]::FromBase64String("YvCLyl0B3E2tjT6gUbW8RA==")
$hex = -join ($string | %{$_.tostring("X").padleft(2,"0")})
$search = $hex -replace '(..)','\$1'
$adUser = Get-AdUser -LDAPFilter "(ms-ds-consistencyguid=$search)"
```